# Add javascript in script tag with React Helmet to HEAD element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, head, react-helmet

I have to add this javascript: `var myData = { "myPageType":"foo" }` in a `<script>` tag to HEAD element in my React app (on a specific page).

Is this the correct way:

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet-async';

<Helmet>
 <script>
   {`var myData = { "myPageType":"foo" }`}
 </script>
</Helmet>
```

Comment: You cannot actually render HTML inside of JSX. You can use one of the `dangerous` methods of doing this, but it is very, very, not recommanded. https://blog.logrocket.com/using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-a-react-application/

Comment: Also, this is not a correct way of doing things. If you want to declare an `analtricsData` variable inside of a component, it should be declared inside of the `Helmet` component.

Comment: @Dimitar but it's inside `Helmet` component right? I only have to render above `script` inside HEAD elementet.

Comment: Is there any issue with your code? Why do you need this to be added to the `<head>` specifically?

Comment: @dbuchet Because it has to do with another third party script and I have to load them in order

Comment: So, is there any issue with the code you provided? Looks like it works for me

Comment: Yeah. So I wanted to double check if this javascript: `var myData = { "myPageType":"foo" }` is injected in the correct way